# How to deploy an aab file on device?

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-app-bundle

in my android app if I want to update APK file I use this:

```
adb install -r some_my.apk
```

Nice. It's work.
Now I sign my bundle and as result Android Studio 3.5. generate : **AAB** (Android App Bundle) file.
Nice.

Now I install prev app from Google Play. And I want to update my app by **AAB**.

How I can do this?

If I try this:

```
adb install -r some_my.aab
```

I get error:

```
adb.exe: need APK file on command line
```

Comment: You can't do it. Android App Bundles is a publishing format. You have to use the bundletool to extract akp from aab

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android App Bundles is a **publishing format** and you **can't** install the aab file on a device.

You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/#build).

> An app bundle is different from an APK in that **you can’t deploy one to a device.** Rather, it’s a upload format that includes all your app’s compiled code and resources in a single build artifact.

You can extract the apks files from the aab file using the [**`bundletool`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/#bundletool) command.

**To generate an APK set** for all device configurations (signed with a debug key) you can use:

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

**To deploy your app from an APK set**, use the install-apks

```
bundletool install-apks --apks=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

Comment: If anyone else is looking for it, the official docs (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) say you can download it from here - https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases